# Function returning unexpected value

Tags: c, arrays, string, output

I have written a function like this, when the parameter `x` is even it doesn't work as desired, for example if I type `printf("%s",maxCharac(2))` in main it will print "aa" and an extra character next to it, but with an odd number it works properly.

```
char *maxCharac(int x)
{
    char *str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*x);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {            
        str[i]='a';
    }
    return str;   
}
```

Comment: don't forget to 0-terminate your string. that's the issue. duplicate link, someone?

Comment: Read the requirements of `printf`.

Comment: `printf("%.*s",2, maxCharac(2))` to print a character array as a "string" that may lack a _null character_.

Comment: Also, do not neglect to free allocated memory once you're done with it.

Comment: Please include information as to what the desired behavior of your function is. For something this simple it isn't too hard to figure out but in general it is important information

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C need to be terminated by a NUL (`'\0'`) character at the end, so you always have to allocate one extra space to store that. Here is your code corrected to fix that.

```
char *maxCharac(int x)
{
    char *str=malloc(sizeof(char)*(x+1));
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {            
        str[i]='a';
    }
    str[x]='\0';
    return str;   
}
```

Comment: or `memset(str,x,'a')` then null terminate :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to output a character array as a string (a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character) while the array does not contain a string.

Either you should output a fixed number of elements of the character array. Or you should store a string in the character array.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *maxCharac(int x)
{
    char *str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*x);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {            
        str[i]='a';
    }

    return str;   
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        char *s = maxCharac( i );
        printf( "%*.*s\n", i, i, s );

        free( s );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *maxCharac(int x)
{
    char *str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*x + 1);
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < x; i++ )
    {            
        str[i]='a';
    }

    str[i] = '\0';

    return str;   
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        char *s = maxCharac( i );
        printf( "%s\n", s );

        free( s );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Chris Turner, you should terminate your string with `\0`

Alternately you can also use `calloc` to allocate memory rather than `malloc`, as `calloc` returns memory by setting it to zeros